# Same height of divs + responsive design - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a footer, with 4 columns in bootstrap. I would like to have same height of each div. Is there any way to do that?

Additionally, Try to resize the view window to see what happens when width is smaller(responsive design), I would like to get it working too.

JSBin : **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sugim/2/edit)**

Code:

My html:

```
<div class="row footer">
    <div class="col-sm-3 leftspan footer-menu col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="footer-title">
             The Trust
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            xxx</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            xxx</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            yyy</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            xxx</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="separator">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 leftspan footer-menu col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="footer-title">
             Connect with us
        </div>
        <table class="footer-image-links">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://facebook.com">
                <img src="/../_layouts/images/icon-facebook.png"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://twitter.com">
                <img src="/../_layouts/images/icon-twitter.png"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://linkedin.com">
                <img src="/../_layouts/images/icon-linkedin.png"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://youtube.com">
                <img src="/../_layouts/images/icon-youtube.png"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="separator">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 leftspan footer-menu col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="footer-title">
             Useful links
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            xxx</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            yyy</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            zzz</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            xxx</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            zzz</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            yyy</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="separator">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 footer-menu col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="footer-title">
             For staff
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            zzz</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            xxx</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href=".">
            ccc</a></li>
            <li id="LoginFooter" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx">
            vvv</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="separator">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.footer
{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.footer-menu
{
    background: #344754;
}

.footer .footer-image-links img
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-menu .separator
{
    border-right: 2px dotted #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-menu .footer-title
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #B4D22A;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
}

.footer-menu .mini-logo
{
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.footer a
{
    color: white;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
}

.footer li
{
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.copyright
{
    background: #B4D22A;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

.copyright > div
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `footer-menu` class in your question has a height attribute and the jsbin does not.  Adding the height value answers your first question doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I have removed it for purpose of this question. This was my work-around to get it working somehow. I will edit code in a secod

Comment: If it's a footer, then you probably want the height to be static.  What do you now like about setting the height via css?

Comment: problem is when I'm changing width of viewport, when div width is changing, my test does not fit in one line, and height is not enough

Comment: Those are two different issues.  What would you like to happen if the width is reduced?  Hide a div or two?  Hide the whole footer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this shameless rip of a bootply helps you, see http://www.bootply.com/92230

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Equal Height Example</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div id="equalheight">      

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>one line of copy</p>
          </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>lots and lots of copy lots and lots of copy lots and lots of copy lots and lots of copy Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
              Quisque mauris augue</p>
          </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>one line of copy</p>
          </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>one line of copy</p>
          </div>
      </div>              

  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div id="equalheight">      

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>one line of copy</p>
          </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>lots and lots of copy lots and lots of copy lots and lots of copy lots and lots of copy Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
              Quisque mauris augue</p>
          </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>one line of copy</p>
          </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 demo">
          <div class="info-block"><!-- BODY BOX-->
              <p>one line of copy</p>
          </div>
      </div>              

  </div>
```

Comment: This works when all 4 columns are displayed in one row without responsive design, when I'm changing width of viewport to lower, its not working: http://jsbin.com/sugim/4/edit

Comment: you might want to go for a javascript solution then, this will work in most of the cases

Answer (score 1):

You could use this little jQuery script. It measures the height of each section and then uses the maximum height for all of them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   getColHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    getColHeight();
});

function getColHeight() {
    heightArrayHeading = [];
    $('.footer .footer-menu').each(function() {
        $(this).css('height', '');
        heightArrayHeading.push($(this).outerHeight());
    });
    $('.footer-menu').css('height', Math.max.apply(Math, heightArrayHeading));
}
```

You don't really need this part, it's just for demonstration purposes when you resize the browser:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    getColHeight();
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/wivinayi/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc). Using JavaScript, the example updates the height of the containers every time the window gets re-sized.

Comment: Is a JavaScript optimal for that? I would preffer css if it is possible